# Marketplace windows phone beta test Error code: 805a0194

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, marketplace

After adding the application in the Marketplace for beta testing, when I try to open a link in the application beta testers shows Error code: 805a0194. And none of the testers can download the application to test ... what to do? what is this error? After adding an application to the App Hub's been 2 days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows error codes like that are fairly easy to reverse-engineer.  The 8 makes it a fatal error.  The 0x5a is the 'facility code', an indication what component caused the error.  90 is undocumented right now in WinError.h, probably means "Windows Phone".  The last word is the error code.

0x194 = 404.  The Universal Internet File-not-found Error Code.  Something wrong with the url you use.

Comment: You say easy, I say black magic.  Can you give me a link with a guide to doing this?  Especially one that doesn't require cracking open Windows headers.

Comment: If you don't want to look in the header files then the best link is stackoverflow.com

Comment: Fair point.  I thought I remembered there being some MSDN article listing those codes or a process to break them apart.  Ever seen anything like that?  Seems like it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Beta submission takes 4 hours to complete – the app then becomes “published”. It takes another 8 hours before the app becomes available for download.

Comment: +1; Good point, and seems like this could be a problem on the same day.  The question does specify "After adding an application to the App Hub's been 2 days", so maybe there are other problems too.

Comment: These times are average(ish). :) I have experienced everything from a few hours to days.