# HTTP Status code to HRESULT mapping

Tags: c++, http-status-codes, hresult

I'm looking at developing a COM wrapper library in C++ for an RESTful web service, and would like to know if there is any standard approach for mapping HTTP Status code values to HRESULTs that will be returned over the COM API. I've had a scan through the definitions in WinError.h, but don't see anything that is appropriate. I know that you can define your own range of HRESULT values, but (as always) I'd prefer to go with a standard approach if one exists.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Nothing standard, you could ab/use [Windows Phone error codes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777955/17034).  Just don't, make your own HRESULTs.  Set the Customer bit, a billion is enough for everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [BitsMsg.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362823(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft SDK for a set of HTTP Status codes

e.g. 404 is defined as:

```
#define BG_E_HTTP_ERROR_404              0x80190194L
// ^^ The requested URL does not exist on the server.
```

To view these codes online, use the following links: [HRESULTS: FACILITY_HTTP](http://joshpoley.blogspot.ru/2011/09/hresults-facilityhttp.html) or [BitsMsg.h](https://github.com/nihon-tc/LFMtest/blob/master/header/Microsoft%20SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Include/BitsMsg.h)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, this was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for and failing to find myself.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SDK 8.0 introduced `HRESULT`s for almost all the HTTP status code in `winerror.h`, for example:

```
#define HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80190194L)
```

If you examined all the values for `HTTP_E_*`, you may found that the error code part of `HRESULT` is just the HTTP status code. Then, you may define a macro for converting any http status code to HRESULT:

```
#define HRESULT_FROM_HTTP(code) MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_HTTP, code)
```