# How to open the Windows Store page for a specific WP app from a WP8 app (MarketplaceDetailTask?)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store, marketplace

To open the Windows Store page for the current app, we generally use code like this:

```cs
MarketplaceDetailTask marketPlaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketPlaceDetailTask.Show();
```

But how to open the Windows Store page for another published product? Am I right if I call something like that:

```cs
var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=d1a235ce-...-040e"));
```

or that:

```cs
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = "http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=d1a235ce-...-040e";
task.Show();
```

Is there a dedicated task like MarketplaceDetailTask to open the specific product page?

Comment: Your error code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777822/marketplace-windows-phone-beta-test-error-code-805a0194. Seems to be that the URL you entered isn't valid.

Comment: @cybermonkey, the link is correct. I can open it manually without any problems in the built-in WP IE browser and using any web-browser on my pc.

Comment: @cybermonkey, the link you placed is useless for me.

Comment: I checked that. Even on the emulator the correct Windows Phone Store app is opened. If the app has just been published, it may take some time bofore it gets propagated to all the stores. And the three dots in your code are just to obscure your app real id, you don't actually have them in your code, right? ;)

Comment: @lisp, I found the problem - I called MarketplaceReviewTask instead of the code I should use! And yes, the ellipsis just obscures the real app id not to be an advertising here ;)

Comment: @cybermonkey, can you very first comment as I found the problem in my code?

Comment: @TecMan What do you mean?

Comment: @cybermonkey, I mean that the error 805a0194 was not raised by the code snippets we are discussing (sorry - my fault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `MarketplaceDetailTask` with the guid of the app you want to show

```
var marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "d1a235ce-...-040e";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Comment: Excellent!! This leads directly to the Store, without opening the browser first and then redirecting to the corresponding Store page.